# User Control in Pivot, binding not work

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, data-binding, windows-phone-8

I'm developing windows phone 8 app.  I have a customer `UserControl` called  `SelectableButton`.  The constructor of it is as below:

```
public SelectableButton()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
}
```

The xaml of it is like this:

```
<Grid>    
    <TextBlock x:Name="ButtonTextBlock"                  
        Text="{Binding SelectableButtonText, Mode=TwoWay}"
        SomeOtherCode
    />
    ...
</Grid>
```

The `SelectableButtonText` is a property of this `UserControl`:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectableButtonTextProperty =  
DependencyProperty.Register(
                "SelectableButtonText", typeof(string), 
                typeof(SelectableButton),
                null
                );
```

Now I use this `SelectableButton` in a `Pivot`.  I want to bind the `SelectableButtonText` property to some data.  This is the `DataTemplate` used in a `Pivot` called `PivotTestContent`:

```
<ShareControl:SelectableButton
    SelectableButtonText="{Binding question}"
    ...
    >
</ShareControl:SelectableButton>
```

The `question` is from the `ItemsSource` of this `Pivot`:

```
PivotTestContent.ItemsSource = quizs;
```

The `quizs` is a `List<>` of `WCCQuizText`

```
quizs = new List<WCCQuizText>();
```

And the `question` is a property member of `WCCQuizText`:

```
public String question
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

After all these work, I find that the `Binding` cant find the property `question`.  It seems that because of this line in the constructor of `SelectableButton`:

```
DataContext = this;
```

The Binding will look for the property `question` in Class `SelectableButton`, not from the `ItemsSouce`.  Because if I bind `question` directly to some `TextBlock.Text`, it will work.  But when I bind it to my UserControl, it can't be found.
So anybody know how to deal with this?

---

If I do like this, I can show the binding text correctly, the TextBlock is in the Pivot, too.

```
   <TextBlock
       Name="TextBlockQuestion"
       Text="{Binding question}"
       ....
       >
   </TextBlock>
```

And my Binding:

```
<ShareControl:SelectableButton
    SelectableButtonText="{Binding Text, ElementName=TextBlockQuestion}"
    ....
    >
</ShareControl:SelectableButton>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. It is caused by `DataContext = this`. Normally your `UserControl` would have context set to an instance of `WCCQuizText` but you are overwriting it with an instance of your `UserControl`. Try removing that line, give `UserControl` some name and and change your binding, within `UserControl`, to something like:

```
<UserControl x:Name="SomeName" ... >
   ....
   <TextBlock ... Text="{Binding ElementName=SomeName, Path=SelectableButtonText}"
```

also `TextBlock` is display control and it will always be one way binding so you can skip `Mode=TwoWay`

Comment: Hi @dkozl, thank you for your quick response.  Why I add DataContext = this; in my usercontrol's constructor is because I have to bind some control's property to its DependencyProperties, not only the Text.  So I think if I delete this line, I have to do some work in the xaml.  Any suggestions?

Comment: If you delete `DataContext = this;` and give `UserControl` a name you can then bind other control properties just like `SelectableButtonText` so by `ElementName`. This is how you can keep current `DataContext` and still bind `UserControl` properties.

Comment: Hi @dkozl, I think I know what you mean now!  Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi @dkozl, your suggestion works well.  But I find that by this method, the appearance of the UI becomes slow.  It takes a second to show my usercontrol.  If I use  `DataContext  = this; ` it is quick.  Do you know why?  Thank you.

Comment: I did not come across any performance issues caused by using `ElementName`. Times should be same in both cases.

Comment: Thank you dkozl.  I really test the code, and get different ui performance.  Maybe there are something else I ignored.  I'll try to figure out.

Comment: hi dkozl, do you know the reason of this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21202062/wp8-binding-not-work-for-customized-button   It's similar to this one.  Thank you.